# Use two ways for outputting to System.out, but why only the way in front outputs?

Tags: java, io

Within a method, I experimented with  two ways of outputing to `System.out`: one via `OutputStreamWriter` and the other via `PrintWriter`. I found that only the one which is in the front will output, but the one behind will not. Why is that?

Is it because when the first's writer is closed implicitly, it will also close `System.out`?

How can I make the two ways (one after the other) both output?

```
try (BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter (new PrintWriter(System.out, true))) //  specify System.out for the output stream and "true" for automatic flushing.
    {
    bw.write("system.out->printwriter->bufferedwriter");
    bw.write("\n");
    // to make sure the content be printed.
    // need to flush the output from the buffer to destination
    // You can call flush or close 
    bw.flush();
    }
catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



try ( BufferedWriter bw2 = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out)))
    {
    bw2.write("system.out->outputstreamwriter->bufferedwriter");
    bw2.write("\n");
    // need to flush the output from the buffer to destination      
    bw2.flush();
    }
catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

will output only `system.out->printwriter->bufferedwriter`

```
try ( BufferedWriter bw2 = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out)))
    {
    bw2.write("system.out->outputstreamwriter->bufferedwriter");
    bw2.write("\n");
    // need to flush the output from the buffer to destination      
    bw2.flush();
    }
catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

try (BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter (new PrintWriter(System.out, true))) //  specify System.out for the output stream and "true" for automatic flushing.
    {
    bw.write("system.out->printwriter->bufferedwriter");
    bw.write("\n");
    // to make sure the content be printed.
    // need to flush the output from the buffer to destination
    // You can call flush or close 
    bw.flush();
    }
catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

will output only `system.out->outputstreamwriter->bufferedwriter`

Comment: That is the whole point of try-with-resources. If you have`try(resource){task}` it will automatically close `resource` after task, or after task will throw any exception. Closing any writer or stream also closes its wrapping writer/streams.

Comment: How can I make either way close their Writer but not close underlying System.out, so that the following way can still use System.out?

Comment: Don't use try-with-resources if you don't want to automatically close them. Simple try like `try{ BufferedWriter bw2 = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out)); bw2.write(..); bw2.flush(); }` should be enough.

Comment: Do I need to close `bw2` somewhere?

Comment: That depends on what it wraps. If it is `System.out` then we usually don't close it which means we also don't want to close classes which *decorate/wrap* it. But if you wrap lets say FileWriter then sure, you should close it.